Very basic question about crates, packages and modules in rust
 ~/rust/first
   src
  │  app
  │ │  src
  │ │ │  lib.rs
  │ │ └  entry.rs                  E
  │ └  Cargo.toml
  └  main.rs                     E 
   Cargo.lock                     
   Cargo.toml                     

This is my first project I am setting up myself in rust.
There is a struct Entry{} in src/app/src/entry.rs.
The top-level Cargo.toml lists members = ["src/app"] in its [workspace] section.
The app-level Cargo.toml defines [package]name="app".
In the top-level main.rs I simply have let app = app::Entry::new();, but the compiler says "use of undeclared crate or module app".
Why is declaring the package "app" in the subdir, and then defining it as a member in the workspace at top-level, not enough for Entry to be seen at the top-level main.rs?
If I add app = { path = "./src/app" } to the dependencies section, then it works.
But then why have workspace members?
What am I missing?


A workspace is a collection of one or more packages, called
workspace members, that are managed together.
The key points of workspaces are:

Common commands can run across all workspace members, like cargo check --workspace.
All packages share a common Cargo.lock file which resides in the   workspace root.
All packages share a common output directory, which defaults to a   directory named target in the workspace root.
Sharing package metadata, like with workspace.package.
The [patch], [replace] and [profile.*]   sections in Cargo.toml are only
recognized in the root manifest, and   ignored in member crates'
manifests.


-- https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/cargo/reference/workspaces.html
Workspace members are not automatically dependencies of each other. This is actually impossible, since that will imply a cyclic dependency between crates.

So in my case, the best suggestion is to introduce the dependency? Or, is it better to put the main executable into an independent package itself, which then introduces a dependency to the app crate? Trying to figure out best practices, and not having to ask such basic questions again.

@unsafe_where_true I think making main depend on app is more natural.

Duh, it just now occurred to me to do a search for "rust modules and packages best practices", which yielded https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-00-managing-growing-projects-with-packages-crates-and-modules.html. Looks like that's what I was missing, reading now.
